# How to Json Decode in PHP using Services_JSON package of pear(PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string )

Tags: php, json, pear

I want to encode/decode an array using JSON . As i have php 5.1.6 , i am  using pear's (http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=198) package.
Using it i can encode but , i am unable to decode i tried to read the doc , but didn't understand anything.Here is my code:

```
<?php  include("/home/gpreeti/php/JSON.php");
$json = new Services_JSON();
$marks = array(
            "mohammad" => array (
               "physics" => 35,
               "maths" => 30,
               "chemistry" => 39
            ),

            "qadir" => array (
               "physics" => 30,
               "maths" => 32,
               "chemistry" => 29
            ),

            "zara" => array (
               "physics" => 31,
               "maths" => 22,
               "chemistry" => 39
            )
         );
$marks=$json->encode($marks);
print"$marks\n";
$marks = $json->decode($marks);
#var_dump($marks);
print"$marks";
?>
```

On running it , i am getting this

```
{"mohammad":{"physics":35,"maths":30,"chemistry":39},"qadir":{"physics":30,"maths":32,"chemistry":29},"zara":{"physics":31,"maths":22,"chemistry":39}}
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /servers/scratch05/gpreeti/php_pgms/test_json.php on line 26
```

Please Help,
Thanks

Comment: Hi, It is because you tried to use `print` to print an Object,`print` only works for string, try using `print_r($marks)` instead.

Comment: Can't i convert it back to its initial form in any way..

Comment: According to the error message, it has been decoded back to array successfully, you just have to use `print_r` to print it.

Comment: i want it as a mutidimensional array not an object.

Comment: try this `var_dump( (array) $marks);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have array/object you need to display it using `print_r / var_dump`. print is used for string

```
$marks=$json->encode($marks);
print"$marks\n";
$marks = $json->decode($marks);
#var_dump($marks);
print_r($marks); //change this line
```

**EDIT** To get array you need to do following changes:

```
$json = new Services_JSON(SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE);
$marks = $json->decode($marks);
```

Comment: but i am getting it as object not array as you can seestdClass Object
(
    [mohammad] => stdClass Object
        (
            [physics] => 35
            [maths] => 30
            [chemistry] => 39
        )

    [qadir] => stdClass Object
        (
            [physics] => 30
            [maths] => 32
            [chemistry] => 29
        )

    [zara] => stdClass Object
        (
            [physics] => 31
            [maths] => 22
            [chemistry] => 39
        )

)

Comment: Hi Mr.Desai, I am facing a problem to do JSON encode in case of special characters like &,+,<,>* etc.Please suggest something.Thanks....

Comment: My JSON format gets break while insertion in database , due to which my data is not displayed on the web.

Comment: Can you see this @B.Desai